# How to change a background image in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

(excusing for my bad english)

I have a couple of divs. They all should have the same background image. So I've given them the same class. in style.css I set the background image for this class by URL. All works fine.
But now I want to change the background image. So I've given the divs an `onclick` function.
This function places the new background image under the old background image.

I've tried a lot:

First I've tried to reset the URL in my onclick function:

```
chal = document.getElementById('chal' + x + n);
chal.style.backgroundImage = "url('../../../images/backgrounds/challenge_unknown_gold.png')";
```

I thought it would replace the background image, but the old one was still displayed.

Then I´ve deleted the first background image, to see, that the change order works.
and it worked. So if there was no background image set before, the new background image displays.

Now I know that my new background will be loaded.
So I´ve tried to set the first background in javascript and deleted the background-image in CSS:
`document.getElementsByClassName("")[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('');`

It also works. The first background image is loaded (just the first but anyway). But if I click nothing happens.

Now I tried to delete the first background before setting the new one:

```
  chal.style.backgroundImage = "";
  chal.style.removeProperty("background-image");
  chal.style.background = "none";
```

But all these tries didn´t work. The only thing that changed is that i now can see the edges of my new background image under my old background image.

So I don´t know how to fix this, without producing a lot of maybe not necessary code.
Maybe make every div a second with the new background and work with display: none. But I hope You could help me, to find a smarter way.

Thanks!

Here is the Code:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    [...]
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="snake_style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div>
       <div id="chalA1" class="challenges bronze" onclick="giveXP('A', 1)"></div>
       <div id="chalA2" class="challenges bronze" onclick="giveXP('A', 2)"></div>
       [...]
       <div id="chalB1" class="challenges bronze" onclick="giveXP('B', 1)"></div>
       <div id="chalB2" class="challenges bronze" onclick="giveXP('B', 2)"></div>
       [...]
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="snake_script.js"></script>
  </main>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.challenges {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    margin: 0.25rem;
    padding:0;
    border: none;
}
.bronze{
    background-image: url(../../../images/backgrounds/challenge_unknown_bronze.png);
}
.silver {
    background-image: url(../../../images/backgrounds/challenge_unknown_silver.png);
}
.gold {
    background-image: url(../../../images/backgrounds/challenge_unknown_gold.png);
}
```

**javascript:**

```
let chal;

function giveXP(x, n) {
[...]
     chal = document.getElementById('chal' + x + n);
     chal.style.backgroundImage = "";
     chal.style.backgroundImage = "url('../../../images/backgrounds/challenge_unknown_gold.png')";
[...]
                     
}
```

Comment: `chal.style.backgrond` should probably be `background`, is this is your code or just a typo?

Comment: Sry, its a typo.
It still not works.

Comment: Remove the single quotes around the URL of the image.

Comment: You can see the edges of your new background image under the old background image? That's strange. What do you get for `console.log(chal.getAttribute('style'));`

Comment: background-image: url("../../../images/backgrounds/challenge_new.png");
I renamed the picture. So in the console is the new, but the old one is still there.

Comment: I am guessing that there are two elements, one element with the new background, and another one with the old background; the first element (with new background) is behind the second element (with old background).

Comment: omg I´m sorry.
You are right.
My Bad :/

Answer (score 0):

**When you are changing bg-image using JavaScript then don't wrap you path inside quotes**

Problem due to quotes:

[image: Console Image]

Change this:

```
chal.style.backgroundImage = "url('../../../images/backgrounds/challenge_unknown_gold.png')";
```

To this:

```
chal.style.backgroundImage = "url(../../../images/backgrounds/challenge_unknown_gold.png)";
```

Here is a example you can see:

```js
const bgImage = document.querySelector('.bg-image');
        const changeBgBtn = document.querySelector('.change-bg-btn');

        changeBgBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            bgImage.style.backgroundImage = `url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/19/15/32/laptop-1839876_1280.jpg)`;
            bgImage.style.backgroundPosition = 'left center';
        })
```

```css
* {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .bg-image {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/23/14/45/coding-1853305_1280.jpg");
            background-position: top right;
            background-size: cover;

            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .change-bg-btn {
            padding: 14px 20px;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #fff;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 1.2rem;
        }
```

```html
<div class="bg-image">
      <button class="change-bg-btn">Change Background</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would removing the single quotes help?

Comment: @AHaworth I have added an image in answer you can see the problem.

Comment: Your quotes `'` convert into `&quot;`  and it will affect you image path.

Comment: If you try adding single quotes to your example, the result still works (tested in Chrome and Firefox). Also, even though it contains `&quot;` in the element inspector, if you use `the_element.getAttribute('style')` you can see that the value actually contains `"`.

Comment: @qrsngky That's great! but it didn't work in my chrome.